# How can I make these strings into decimals using map (GAS)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make sure that the resulting column will onlu contain numbers, but it keeps coming as string.

```
function moveColsWesbanco() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('New Entry');
  var debitsCredits = sourceSheet.getRange('A7:D');
  var values = debitsCredits.getValues();
  let amounts2 = values.filter(o => o[0] != '').map(e => e[2] != '' ? e[3] = Number.parseFloat(e[2]) : Number.parseFloat(e[3]));
  let allTypes = [];
  for (val in amounts2) {
    allTypes.push(typeof val)
  };
  Logger.log('Types within it: ' + allTypes)
  return;
}
```

Here are the logs:
[image]

So...I wonder what I'm missing here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when "for in" is used like `for (val in amounts2) {}`, `val` is the index. And, it's the string type. I think that this is the reason of your issue. In this case, how about using "for of" as follows?

#### Modified script:

```
for (var val of amounts2) {
  allTypes.push(typeof val)
};
```

#### References:

- [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still running into these silly mistakes.

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. It's no problem. As the additional information, for example, when you want to retrieve `val` as the index of the number value, you can use. `for (var val = 0; val < amounts2.length; val++) { ,,, }` In this case, `val` is the index of the number type. Or, in your situation, I think that `map` can be also used. It's like `var allTypes = amounts2.map((value, index) => ({[value]: typeof value, [index]: typeof index}))`. In this case, both value and index can be retrieved.